# Looking for an angular image cropper library where the image moves instead of the cropping box

Tags: angular, frontend, web-component, image-cropper

I'm looking for image cropping where the image moves instead of the crop box, like in the example below. The cropping component example is `<ly-img-cropper>` from alyle https://alyle.io/components/image-cropper

To use that component, I have to install the whole `alyle` library, which comes with many other components I don't need. Has anyone seen something similar?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I took a quick look at the source code for alyle, and while I can't be sure just by looking, it looks like it should be tree-shakeable, so I think that you shouldn't worry about "installing the whole library". Your compiled version should only have the parts that you use.

So, if you like the library, use it.

Alternatively, the source is available, and is MIT licensed, so you could fork it and rip out everything you don't need, as long as you adhere to the license.